# 3 same foreign keys in one table, select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table Errors, this table have 3 foreign keys - ID_empl, ID_empl1, ID_empl2 from same table - Employer where ID_empl is primary key and also have other atributes Name and Surname.ID_empl refering to who repair the error, ID_empl1 refering to who report the error amd ID_empl refering to who take over the error.

Now i want to do SELECT on this table Errors and i want to have statement like : `ID_empl - name, surname; ID_empl1 - name, surname; ID_empl2 - name, surname` . If there was only 1 FK lets say ID_empl i would do `SELECT er.ID_empl, em.name||em.surname as EMPLOYER from employer em, error er where er.ID_empl=em.ID_empl`. But i dont know how to do this this with 3 same FKs and i need this info (name+surname) 3 times for every FK.

Little Q2:  i have table Company which have some atributes  and FK ID_empl refering to who manage this company. This FK can be null. Now when i want to do :`select e.name||e.surname as EMPLOYER from employer e, company c where e.ID_empl=c.ID_empl` i get only rows where ID_empl is not bull, but i want all rows.  There is a problem with join that ID_empl can be null but i dont know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please clean up your formatting, and also show us some table structure?

Comment: Yes i will do it, but right now i am on mobile phone and its 3 am here. Also i will delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like a job for a multiple join. Using your syntax (old, obsolete, not recommended - even Oracle themselves recommend using the modern syntax), it would be

```
select [whatever], emp1.name || ' ' || emp1.surname as repaired,
                   emp2.name || ' ' || emp2.surname as reported,
                   emp3.name || ' ' || emp3.surname as took_over
from errors er, employer emp1, employer emp2, employer emp3
where er.ID_empl  = emp1.ID_empl
  and er.ID_empl1 = emp2.ID_empl
  and er.ID_empl2 = emp3.ID_empl
```

This way the name and surname for "repaired" (the person who repaired the error) is read from table "employer" for id = ID_empl in the "error" table (you said that is the foreign key for the column that contains ID for who repaired the error), the name and surname for "reported" is selected from "employer" table for the id = ID_empl1 in table "error" (with the foreign key for the person who reported the error), and similar for "took over."

The proper, modern, SQL standard, recommended join syntax is

```
..... from errors er join employer emp1 on er.ID_empl  = emp1.ID_empl
                     join employer emp2 on er.ID_empl1 = emp2.ID_empl
                     join employer emp3 on er.ID_empl2 = emp3.ID_empl
```

For your second question, you simply need an OUTER join. For this, too, there is "old style" proprietary Oracle syntax, which Oracle itself **does not recommend**. The proper, modern, SQL standard syntax for your outer join is:

```
select [whatever], e.name || ' ' || e.surname
from company c left outer join e on c.ID_empl = e.ID_empl
```